# Store each value of a 'foreach' loop into a string array

Tags: c#

Consider:

```
 string[] collection = new string[3]{"hi","hello","test"}; 
 string [] elements = new string [3];
 int index = 0;
 foreach(string anode in collection)
 {
   string[index++] = anode;
 }
```

Comment: What is `somecollection`? Do you know that there will be (no more than) three elements in it? What string do you want for each element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/599373/1618257:

```
List<string> elements = new List<string>();
foreach(xmlnode anode in somecollection)
{
  elements.Add("string");
}
```